# Ruby practical for Android Development?

Tags: android, ruby

I am trying to break into a bit of development and have been advised Ruby is quite an easy / powerful language to get started on.

My main hope for learning a programming language was to break into mobile development.  I have heard Ruby can be used for Android development with the right 'kit' but is this a practical language to use for this or will it end up being a more long winded approach than just learning Java from the get go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should be looking at http://rhomobile.com/?

Comment: This looks awsome. And free (as in beer and freedom) too.

Answer (score 14):

I recently read about [Ruboto](http://github.com/ruboto/ruboto). You should check it out too!

Comment: And the rest of the ecosystem can be found here: https://github.com/ruboto

Answer (score 8):

Almost all the documentation on android development is focused on Java, and eclipse.  While I'm not a big fan of Eclipse as an IDE (bloat); it is what the lot use, so it is what I use.

Where you'll find hardship with ruby is when you have to do something that is atypical.. something that is purely android.  It will save you time in the beginning, however as with all high level languages, it will end up costing you more when you need to get "dirty"... The net result will be the same.

I program ruby/rails during my day job and android for my "unpaid".  Both are good languages, but there are strings attached with any language.

Keep in mind also that the Android platform is Java supported.. In this you know if there are new features in OS 5..6..n then you can be sure there is a way to access them in Java. Ruby might be quick to integrate them, but then it depends on the developers (us) of Ruby.  Also keep in mind that on some older devices 1.x..2.x there may be things that run slow when passed through ruby. (I don't know how it's interpreter works)..

Last note.  If you learn Ruby for android, and you apply for a job programming Android, I'm betting they will expect Eclipse/Java not xxx/Ruby

Answer (score 7):

Not very sure of Ruby , but you can surely use JRuby http://code.google.com/p/jruby-for-android/

Comment: jruby for android has been deprecated in favour of ruboto

Comment: Oh snap.. be careful.. ruboto may be depreciated next. :)  Not java though.. Argument against all but java right there..

Comment: The owner asked if for an opinion not tools and frameworks

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to learn mobile development on Android, I would highly suggest sticking with Java.  The Android SDK is Java based, and the majority of documentation and examples (including the official docs) you find will be in Java.

While Ruby is a powerful language, it is primarily used for web development.  You may have a difficult time finding documentation, and support when you're not using standard Android language.

Comment: While web development is probably Ruby's most widely used target environment, that has nothing to do with the Ruby language itself, but with the popularity of the Rails package. So that is an irrelevant and misleading statement when arguing against using Ruby for Android development (about which I am not commenting)

Comment: +1 Your comments are accurate and complete. The difficulty around finding documentation is a valid concern.  Yes the language is supported.  So too is c and assembly, but practically speaking you're not going to find loads of docs on using them.  No way you should get neg votes on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google mainly supports using Java with Eclipse.  While you probably *could* do it with Ruby, I think your best bet is to just use Java and Eclipse.

Comment: And does the same apply for using Ruby to code OS X applications or iOS Applications?  I've seen MacRuby allows for crossover from what I can see?

Comment: I don't know.  I only develop for Android.  That's a whole different question.

Comment: If you want Ruby on IOS.  Ruby motion is built on top of MacRuby.  It is compiled and you have access the to all the native apis.  But do to apple limitations on interpreted languages it does have some limitations.  It has been used on productions apps.