# Ruby practical for OS X app / iOS app development?

Tags: ruby, ios, macos

I posted a [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993998/ruby-practical-for-android-development) recently but for Android development where I was told Android development, while just about possible using Ruby, is far from ideal.

Now I was wondering is it any more practical / possible to use Ruby to develop iOS or OS X apps in one shape or form or will it just be a matter of mastering Ruby then using that as a basis for learning the more complex Objective-C language?

Comment: I don't know about ruby, but with things like monotouch (using .net languages to write iOS apps) it can get you an app but if you really want to develop for iOS and be able to take full advantage of the platform you need to use objective-c. It has a learning curve but it'd not *that* bad. And once you've got the hang of it, it's great (well I prefer it to .net languages)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I guess I will learn Ruby first (new to programming) and use it as a 'jump off point' as suggested previously.

Comment: Have you tried [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/)? You can do most of it in Ruby and fall back to Objective C if you want to do something that is not provided out of the box.

Comment: I haven't seen / used Rhodes but thanks @Augusto I'll give that a look!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rubymotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/).
It's far from free, but if you have U$200 to spare, it might be a good choice.