# Titanium with ruby for android apps

Tags: titanium-mobile

Can anyone share a short example or tutorial for developing android native apps using Titanium with ruby?

In titanium Appcelerator, I am able to see http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Ruby_Development.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not related to Android development.

Look at the tree on the left. "Ruby Development" is under "Web development" (server side).

Everything related to mobile development is under another item - "Titanium development".

However, if you are interesting in using Ruby to develop for Android, you can take a look at this question:
[Ruby practical for Android Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993998/ruby-practical-for-android-development)